# Magento 2.1.3 to 2.2.5 Upgrade Checksum verification of the file failed

Tags: upgrade, composer, magento-2.2.5

I stumbled into this problem while upgrading Magento 2.1.3 to 2.2.5 via composer update. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears it was just my Network that's causing the issue. I transferred to another internet connection and it works fine the upgrade finished successfully.